# DOM reloading after setState function

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Having a small problem with React where when I call a function which setStates, the page reloads on browser and state remains unchanged.

input-area.js:

#updateContent function

```
handleInputSubmit(e){
    this.props.updateContent('Work')
}
```

parent.js:

```
this.state = {
    isActiveWork: false,
}

render(){
    return(
        ...
        <InputArea updateContent = {this.updateContent}/>
        ...
        )

updateContent(content){
        if (content === 'Work'){
            this.setState(state => ({
                isActiveWork: !state.isActiveWork 
            }))
        }
```

everytime `handleInputSubmit` is called, the page on the browser refreshes and `state.isActiveWork`remains false

Comment: try to use callback as arrow function , you use it like this : updateContent=(content)=>{
        if (content === 'Work'){
            this.setState(state => ({
                isActiveWork: !state.isActiveWork 
            }))
        }

Comment: Thank you! this worked!